# Jenkins, cron expression, a job should not run from 15.00 to 16.00

Tags: jenkins, devops, cronexpression, pooling

Simple simple question, i need to run a job all the day (pooling our SVN repositories) but not from 15.00 to 16.00..

For now my configuration does not work.. job ran at 15.36! :(

[image: Here you can see my cron expression]

As you can see my cron expression is **H/30 0-15,16-23 * * ***
What is the problem? is the cron expression that does not work, or  is there something i don't get?

Comment: I suspect the `0-15` is inclusive, and needs to be changed to `0-14`, but it's only a guess

Answer (score 1):

@RemcoGerlich is correct, "0-15,16-23" in the hour specifier is the same as saying "0-23".  You need "0-14,16-23".